# protractor/jasmine get test meta

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to fetch test meta during runtime, especially test name/description.
I'm using `protractor` version 5.3.2 and `jasmine` of version  2.8.8

Past threads on `stackoverflow` relied in `jasmine` to perform this task, but I failed following the instructions/

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did my answer help solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can get this from `jasmine`, it's fairly easy to create a basic reporter and then you can expand on it from there.  Here are [Jasmine docs on custom reporter](https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html)

Here's a basic sample:

```
// specReport.js
class SpecReport {
    // these functions are automatically provided from jasmine, nothing else required
    jasmineStarted(result) {
        console.log(result);
    };

    jasmineDone(result) {
        console.log(result);
    };

    suiteStarted(result) {
        console.log(result);
    };

    suiteDone(result) {
        console.log(result);
    };

    specStarted(result) {
        console.log(result);
    };

    specDone(result) {
        console.log(result);
    };
};

module.exports = SpecReport;
```

And then pull this file into your config and instantiate it during `onPrepare`:

```
// conf.js
const SpecReport = require('./specReport');
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    ... other stuff...

    onPrepare: function() {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReport());
    }
}
```

This will start printing basic properties of the test during runtime which includes suite descriptions, test names etc.